# KnockOutJS conditional comments adding space in the HTML

Tags: html, css, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this problem, but I am not 100% sure that is related with KnockOutJS. In a grid, some of the buttons inside a row are optional, and are being shown depending on the values of the bound item.  I am using conditional binding to show some buttons or other, but apparently, even when they are not show, the still create a space somehow:

[image]

As you can see, a magic space appears between those two buttons.

This is the template code of those 3 columns as I wrote it:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="editDetails">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" class="viewDetails">View</a>
</td>
<td>
    <!-- ko if: (CanEdit()) -->
        <a href="#" class="editPremium">Edit</a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: (!CanEdit()) -->
        <a href="#" class="createCopy">Copy</a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <a href="#" class="viewPremiums">View</a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
</td>
```

There is no CSS associated with those classes.

As you can see, there is a button that is not being shown, and maybe the culprit of that space between the other two. This is the code generated as indicated by Google Chrome for that problematic TD:

```
<td>
    <!-- ko if: (CanEdit()) -->
       <a href="#" class="editPremium" style="visibility: visible;">Edit</a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: (!CanEdit()) -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <a href="#" class="viewPremiums">View</a>
</td>
```

So the middle button is not shown (as expected), but an extra space is created between the other two.

How may I get ride of that space between the two buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it work to use the `visible` binding?

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="editPremium" data-bind="visible: CanEdit()">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" class="createCopy" data-bind="visible: !CanEdit()">Copy</a>
    <a href="#" class="viewPremiums">View</a>
</td>
```

Alternatively, you could try removing much of the space around the elements:

```
<td>
    <!-- ko if: (CanEdit()) --><a href="#" class="editPremium">Edit</a><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: (!CanEdit()) --><a href="#" class="createCopy">Copy</a><!-- /ko -->
    <a href="#" class="viewPremiums">View</a>
</td>
```

In general, you'll have less trouble with spacing if you use block elements. You can either use a `div` to enclose each `a` or style the `a` as `display:block;` and add `float:left;` to make them align horizontally.

Comment: Right. If i inlined all the elements, the space disappears. But why is rendering those spaces because de break lines?

Comment: I'm not sure of the why. I expanded my answer with a bit more info though.

Comment: crazy stuff. Thanks a lot :)